# Replace Strings in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace a string in python like this:

```
        private_ips.replace("{",'')
```

The error I get back is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 39, in <module>
    private_ips.replace("{",'')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a `set` object and not an `str` :) Check what is `private_ips` ? `type(private_ips)` ?

Comment: Ah ok. Got it. Derp! :) How can I replace text in a set object?

Comment: You'd have to show some `input`s

Comment: Ok sorry. I'm getting the IPs of aws instances using object path like this: `            tree = objectpath.Tree(instance)
            private_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))` the output looks like this: `{'10.48.136.41'}` and I want to replace '{' and '}'. Thanks

Comment: `private_ips = set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress')).pop()` will return one element from the set. And since it looks like you have only one, that will do, i guess

Comment: OK yeah that's cool. I do have only one IP in this example. But I also have firewalls with up to 20 private IPs. So I want to keep that in some kind of list. But I want to remove the surrounding "{}" characters.

Answer (score 1):

`private_ips` is `set` object. You can use replace only on strings.

To represent set as string take this code snippet:

```
private_ips_as_string = '{' + ', '.join(str(elem) for elem in private_ips) + '}'
```

Comment: So how would someone represent a `set` as a `str`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's back up a little ...

```
tree = objectpath.Tree(instance) 
private_ips = set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))
```

Your initial problem is that you *specifically* converted the return value into a set.  If you don't want a set, then don't convert it to one, or convert it back to something more useful to you.  Since you've failed to provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't fix everything, but I'll use an intuitive leap here ...

- `tree.execute` returns a list of IP addresses.
- You're using `set` to remove duplicate addresses in a list.

If so, you're fine up to this point.  To get the address as a string, I think you want to iterate through the items in the set:

```
for ip_addr in private_ips:
    # Handle ip_addr, a single IP address seen as a str.
```

If you need the addresses lined up, you can always convert back to a list with

```
private_ips = list(private_ips)
```

... and if you *know* there is exactly one addr that you want as a string, you can grab it in one step with

```
single_ip = list(private_ips)[0]
```

... or just grab it directly from your function's return value:

```
single_ip = tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress')[0]
```

---

To explain what *did* happen to you:

- You called a function that return a sequence of some sort.
- You converted that sequence to a set, a common technique for removing duplicates.
- You tried to remove braces from the set, as if it were a string.

The problem is that a set *does not have braces*.  Those braces are a notational convenience; they exist *only* in the `__repr__` (output string representation) of the data type, not in the set itself.  You *cannot* manipulate that representation.  This would be something like trying to remove the up-vote and down-vote arrows from this question by editing the question text: you can't do it, because those are part of the delivery framework.

Similarly, you cannot remove the quotation marks from the ends of a string, because they're not part of the string.

To get rid of the braces, you quit using a `set`: reach inside and pull out the contents as an individual element.